# NodeJS nested app.get operations

Tags: node.js, express

I have several app.get request that find the first object in different collections.

Now I have to create another app.get request that combines the result of the other 2 app.get.

for instance:

```
app.get('/book/', function(req, res){
    res.JSON('book1');
});

app.get('/shelf/', function(req, res){
    res.JSON('shelf36');
});
```

I want to create another app.get that combines both results. Something that would be like:

```
app.get('/booklocation/' , function(req, res){
     1) var book = execute first app.get
     2) var shelf = execute second app.get
     res.JSON('book' + book + ' is at ' + shelf);
});
```

Is this possible? How can I achieve this behaviour without performing the same code over and over again in the different resources that may need the same information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most use cases I think the smart things would be to refactor behavior of your handlers into their own functions which you can then call individually from each route.

```
function getBook(id){...}

function getShelf(id){...}



app.get('/book/', function(req, res){
     var book1 = getBook()
    res.JSON('book1');
});

 app.get('/shelf/', function(req, res){
     var shelf36 = getShelf()
     res.JSON('shelf36');
 });

app.get('/booklocation/' , function(req, res){
    var book = getBook()
    var shelf = getShelf()
    res.JSON('book' + book + ' is at ' + shelf);
});
```

If for whatever reason you can’t use this pattern, there is a module called run middleware that you can use to run the actual routes that works well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-middleware